# Difference between scalaSource and sourceDirectories in sbt

Tags: scala, build, sbt

What is the difference between `scalaSource` and `sourceDirectories`? I have a non-standard directory structure where source code lives in `src/`,

This line works in `build.sbt`:

`scalaSource in Compile := file("src/")`

but not

`sourceDirectories in Compile := Seq(file("src/"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you the whole picture, someone who worked on sbt may see this post later. 
Till then, here is how I reason about this things: [inspect](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings.html)

```
> inspect actual compile:scalaSource
[info] Description:
[info]  Default Scala source directory.
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:sourceDirectory
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:scalaSource

> inspect actual compile:sourceDirectories
[info] Description:
[info]  List of all source directories, both managed and unmanaged.
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info]  compile:managedSourceDirectories
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:sourceDirectories
[info]  *:sourceDirectories
[info]  {.}/compile:sourceDirectories
```

Now this is how I interpret this:
sourceDirectories are ... well ... completely informal ...

Lets see how this is relevant to something like `compile`:

```
> inspect compile
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:compile::compileInputs  <----
[info]  compile:compile::streams

> inspect compile:compile::compileInputs
[info] Dependencies:
...
[info]  compile:compile::sources  <----
...

> inspect compile:compile::sources
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:<build-uri>}<project-id>/compile:sources    
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:compile::sources
[info]  compile:sources  <----
```

This task is delegated, we can see where we came from in `Reverse dependencies` with `inspect actual`, regular inspect woudn't show them.

```
> inspect actual compile:sources
[info] Description:
[info]  All sources, both managed and unmanaged.
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:doc
[info]  compile:compile::compileInputs
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:unmanagedSources   <----
[info]  compile:managedSources

> inspect compile:unmanagedSources
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
...

> inspect compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:javaSource
[info]  compile:scalaSource  <----
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:sourceDirectories
[info]  compile:unmanagedSources
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Sources come in many kinds: Scala and Java, managed and unmanaged. `sourceDirectories in Compile` combines all of them, but you wouldn't normally want to set it directly; normally you'd set the more specific setting that applies to the particular kind of source you're trying to tell sbt the location of.

Note that `baseDirectory.value / "src"` would be more correct than `file("src")` (it works in more scenarios: subprojects, external projects, etc).